# PHP Array issue when looping and echoing

Tags: php, arrays, loops, echo

I'm having trouble getting the array to work right, let me show you the code here

```
function scanArray(){
$al = sizeof($_userLoaders);
echo $al. "<br />";
for ($tr = 0; $tr <= $al; $tr++) {
echo  "value: " .$tr. "<br />";
echo $_userLoaders[$tr];


}



}

//Fetch user's loaders.

$_userLoaders;

function get_user_loaders(){ 

         $con = connectToMySQL();//connects to my_sql

        mysql_select_db("my_database", $con);//connect database

        $t = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM someTable
        WHERE value_a=".$_SESSION['value_a']." AND value_b=someValue");
        $x= 0;
        //lets loop through the results and create an array to compare later.
            while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($t)){
             $_userLoaders[$x] = $result['value_c'];
                $x++;
            }
        //lets get all the options for
        print_r($_userLoaders);//this part prints what it should
scanArray();
}
```

okay, I minimized the code above to show you what's going on. Pretty much function `get_user_loaders()` works great. It fetches data from a table in a database, and returns what it should. Second, it makes an array out of it. Again, this part works great. When the `print_r()` method is called it prints what it should, here's an example of what it prints:

```
Array ( [0] => tableValue )
```

yes, at this point it only has one value, please note that this value can vary from no values to 100 values which is why I am using an array. In this case, i'm testing it with one value.

Now, once I call `scanArray()` It doesn't echo the values.

the `scanArray()` function echoes the following:

```
0
value:
```

so what I don't understand is why does it print it out, but it doesn't display the function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $_userLoaders is not defined in scanArray and you have an error there - `for ($tr = 0; $tr <= $al - 1; $tr++) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$_userLoaders` variable is declared outside the function and function `scanArray` knows nothing about it.  You need to either pass that variable in as a parameter:

```
function scanArray($_userLoaders) {
    ...
}
```

with the call at the end being

```
scanArray($_userLoaders);
```

or alternatively declare the variable as `global` inside the function:

```
function scanArray($_userLoaders) {
    global $_userLoaders;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was used to declaring it outside of the function, like in javaScript, and having it automatically be global. I didn't know that you had to declare it as a global variable. Well thank you to both of you gentlemen. I think I'll pass it through the parameters since there are a lot of other php pages that will be working together. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That would be because $_userLoaders is not equal to anything inside your scanArray() function. While it's not good practice, you can add the line:

```
global $_userLoaders;
```

to your scanArray() function and every other function that uses that global variable then, and it should work.